# How to change the value of an element in an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode

I want to change the values of some Elements but my code isn't working.
I have this XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <application id="1">
    <applicationName>Instagram</applicationName>
    <username>test</username>
    <password>123</password>
    <info>test</info>
  </application>
</data>
```

And this C# Code:

```
string applicationName = "Test";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("Data.xml");
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/data/application[@id='1']/applicationName");
node.InnerText = applicationName;
xmlDoc.Save("Data.xml");
```

What is the correct code to change the `applicationName` in the XML-File?

Comment: On behalf of all users here: thanks for posting a question with complete code and data; it is much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify existing XML file with XmlDocument and XmlNode in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558787/how-to-modify-existing-xml-file-with-xmldocument-and-xmlnode-in-c-sharp)

Comment: And an [alternative with XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18508765/60761)

Comment: The code you posted works perfectly for me... are you sure you're looking at the right file? In particular, make sure you look at the output file in ./bin/debug or ./bin/release if you're looking under the solution folder. Can you define "isn't working"?

Comment: I second Marc Gravell. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) and [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string applicationName = "Test";
XDocument xdocument = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
var appName = xdocument.Elements("applicationName").Single();
appName.Value = applicationName;
xdocument.Save("Data.xml");
```

But you should add `System.Xml.Linq` to your using directives first.

Comment: this is *an* approach, but ... it seems unnecessary, especially considering that the code in the question works fine

Comment: @MarcGravell BTW I would always prefer to use LINQ and `XDocument` as I can.

Comment: Sometimes that's perfectly valid - there are advantages and targeted scenarios (and equally: unsupported scenarios) to some tools, and *when folks are using an inappropriate tool*, it is totally legitimate to say "first use the right tool". In this case, however, both tools are perfectly fine and reasonable choices, and *unless there is a good, objective, stated reason*, IMO it is better to help people work with their existing *perfectly legitimate* tool choice. In this case, the code in the question already works perfectly and does the exact thing required. It literally requires zero changes.