# How to create xml element runtime?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to create xml element in runtime in the existing xml file. How do i do that in c#?
For example, there is a xml file as

```
<data value = "1">
 <user>one</user>
</data>
```

I want to create a element in runtime and output should be like this,

```
 <data value = "1">
   <user>one</user>
   <status>used</status>
 </data>
```

Comment: What have you tried already? There is a myriad of ways to do this in C# as well as a number of questions that are already answered on Stack Overflow dealing with this exact issue :-) .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify existing XML file with XmlDocument and XmlNode in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558787/how-to-modify-existing-xml-file-with-xmldocument-and-xmlnode-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build XML in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284324/how-can-i-build-xml-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Use AooendChild() to add new child node. Try Something like following

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

```
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

//Create a new node.
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("Status");
elem.InnerText="used";

//Add the node to the document.
root.AppendChild(elem);
```